# p:graphicImage inside p:dataGrid shows only blank images

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to use byte array (as BLOB saved in DB) to return the StreamedContent to the p:graphicImage, that is inside a p:datagrid, as follows:

```
<p:dataGrid id="dtResults" rows="10" columns="3"
    value="#{searchResultsController.items}" var="item">
    <p:column>
        <p:panel header="#{item.displayName}" style="text-align:center">
            <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%">
                <p:graphicImage binding="#{imagestickiesController.imageforuserid}"
                    width="100" height="100" value="#{imagestickiesController.image}">
                    <f:attribute  name="uID" value="#{item.userID}" />
                </p:graphicImage>
                <h:outputText id="lAboutMe" value="#{item.aboutMe}"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
    </p:column>
</p:dataGrid>
```

This one returns blank images. Is someone have an idea why?

ADDED:
The part of the ImagestickiesController in this context is:

```
  public class ImagestickiesController {

private GraphicImage imageforuserid;

public GraphicImage getImageforuserid(){
    return imageforuserid;
}

public void setImageforuserid(GraphicImage gi){
    imageforuserid = gi;
}

    public StreamedContent getImage(){
        System.out.println("In getImage");
        System.out.println(imageforuserid);
        System.out.println(imageforuserid.getAttributes().get("uID"));
        Long value = (Long)imageforuserid.getAttributes().get("uID");
        if (value!=null)
        {
           Imagestickies curr =  ejbFacade.FindByUserID(value);
           if (curr!=null)
           {
               System.out.println(curr);
                InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(curr.getStickies().getContent());
                StreamedContent res = new DefaultStreamedContent(is);
                return res;
            }
        }
       return null;
    }
}
```

The ejbFacade makes the query to the DB. I've printed the size of the resulted imaged in bytes, and saw it was OK, but still the image is not shown... 
Another thing is that the item (User entity) cannot reach the image within the DB due to restrictions in the design.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `binding` attribute in this particular context doesn't give me a good feeling that you're using it the right way. Remove it. The `value` attribute also doesn't seem to point to the `UIData`'s iterated variable `#{item}`.

Fix it accordingly.

```
<p:graphicImage width="100" height="100" value="#{item.image}">
```

The `Item` class should then have a `private StreamedContent image` property, with a getter.

If that's not an option for some design restrictions in the `Item` class, then you really have to show your `#{imagestickiesController}` code as it's definitely the whole culprit.

Comment: I'll check the iterated item and design restrictions, and i'll be back with results soon...

Comment: I've edited the question and put imagestickiesController after checking the restrictions and finding out that the item cannot get the image...

Comment: Supposedly, if I work with link to file images instead of StreamedContent - it works... but I wish not to handle file linkage, since my solution doesn't consider handling file system... Is there any possible way to handle the image using StreamedContent?